# Best way to handle a many to many relationship in EF6 ASP.NET MVC 5 and retrieve property from navigation property to list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

A few years ago I took over a project from a previous developer and have been working my way through this system and adding to it as well as reconfiguring some aspects of it. The latest thing I've uncovered was a many to many relationship that I haven't handled yet.

I have two tables:

ECAnalysis - which contains active and valid analyses for a given instrument.

ECAnalyte  - which contains active and valid analytes.

One analysis can have many analytes whereas one analyte can be on many analyses (if I'm thinking about this in a correct way from what was left for me).

[image: Table Description]

There is also an intermediate table in my MySQL database called ECAnalysisToECAnalyte which just contains the primary keys of each table.

[image: ECAnalysisToECAnalyte Table]

The EF code is configured as such to be a generic repository because of the large number of entities. So to get data out of the system along with navigation properties there is a method that gets all of the data:

```cs
 public virtual async Task<IList<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties) where T : class
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new EntitiesContext())
                {
                    List<T> list;

                    IQueryable<T> dbQuery = db.Set<T>();

                    foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                        dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

                    list = await dbQuery.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync<T>();


                    return list;
                }

            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Invalid state: {typeof(T).Name} DbSet is null.", ex);
            }
        }
```

This method works correctly for all normal types of relationships and entities but it doesn't seem to work for a many to many relationship.

And to call it in my main application it's used in this manner:

```cs
var data = (from a in await Manager.GetAllAsync<ECAnalysis>(n => n.ECAnalyte)
            select a);
```

My task now has been to get a list of analytes for a given analysis and pass them to a view. My first issue is when I use the method as is with the `AsNoTracking()` I get an exception stating that:

```
When an object is returned with a NoTracking merge option, Load can only be called when the EntityCollection or EntityReference does not contain objects.
```

If I remove the `AsNoTracking()` ***I get the correct list of analytes*** to my view but along with another exception:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

How I'm getting this list of analytes is like this...I know it's probably not the cleanest or most efficient so bear with me:

```cs
 public async Task<JsonResult> GetAnalytes(string sampleType)
        {
            var analysis = (from a in await Manager.AllAsync<ECAnalysis>(b => b.ECAnalyte)
                            where a.Method == "IC" && a.Media == sampleType + " - ANIONS"
                            select a).ToList();

            var ecAnalytes = analysis.FirstOrDefault().ECAnalyte.ToList();

            var analyteList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var item in ecAnalytes)
            {
                analyteList.Add(item.Name);
            };

            return Json(analysis, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    //this is being called from an Ajax method
        }
```

So my questions are:

Is the many to many relationship configured properly for how I want to use it?

Is there a better way to get a list of analytes for a given analysis that doesn't give me an exception?

Comment: A Many-To-Many gives a multi-dimensional result.   Using SelectMany will flatten result by one level.  Try : var ecAnalytes = analysis.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

Comment: Well....that stopped the Exception error but I'm not getting the correct analyte list.
I had to do `var ecAnalytes = analysis.SelectMany(x =>x.ECAnalyte.FirstOrDefault().Name).ToList();` in order to drill down to the Name property.

Comment: You are only getting one so try this instead : var ecAnalytes = analysis.SelectMany(x =>x.ECAnalyte.Select(y => y.Name).ToList()).ToList();

Comment: That got the correct list. I left out the second ToList though:
` var ecAnalytes = analysis.SelectMany(x => x.ECAnalyte.Select(y=>y.Name)).ToList();
`
 Thank you very much! I just couldn't figure out how to flatten the list because it kept returning multiple levels. If you want to put it as an answer I'll mark it.